# Medium Risk Event - Sign-ins from unfamiliar locations

Tags: security, azure, entra-id

In Azure portal how do I disable the Risk Event:

- Medium Risk Event - Sign-ins from unfamiliar locations?

But keep the:

- Medium Risk Event - Sign-ins from anonymous IP addresses
- Medium Risk Event - Impossible travel to atypical locations

The only options I see is to enable High, Medium, and Low. I am not sure where can I find to manage the 3 Medium Sub Events.

Answer (score 0):

About Risk Events setup, you can refer to the operations "Closing risk events manually" in [Azure Directory Identity Potection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-identityprotection)